# How can I use Debug.Log only once in the Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.white);
            Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
        }
    }
}
```

If it hit then log to the console once even if the player is facing the item all the time and then when not facing the item log not hit once too so each time if the player is facing/not facing the item log to the console window once and not nonstop times. Should I use some flags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool raycastSucceed;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            if(!raycastSucceed)
              Debug.Log("Did Hit");
            raycastSucceed = true;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
        }
        else
        {
            if(raycastSucceed)
              Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
            raycastSucceed = false;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.white);
        }
    }
}
```